# Trigger AWS Lambda when timestamp is fulfilled

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

An external process calculates a timestamp related to an ID, for example:

| id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1695221055 |
| 2 | 1695221079 |

I have a Lambda function that I want to trigger when that timestamp is reached, and I need to have the ID of the fulfilled timestamp. In other words, when the time in UTC reaches that timestamp, I want the Lambda function to be triggered having that ID of the timestamp that made it trigger. Please note that this record can be updated due to my external process, and the timestamp may be set to a further date.

The architecture I considered was using a TTL (Time to Live) feature in DynamoDB with that timestamp column set as TTL, and DynamoDB Streams listening to it, so when deleted, trigger my lambda. However, DynamoDB can take up to 48 hours to delete the record, which would result in the deletion event arriving much more later than I require, due to I need almost real time.

Is there a way to achieve this? It doesn't have to be in DynamoDB; another type of architecture may work for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use EventBridge Scheduler. So when you create the item, capture that creation in DynamoDB Streams, have a Lambda function that creates an [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/scheduler.html) that invokes a Lambda function at the time you specify and with the data you require.

EventBridge scheduler has a granularity of 1 min, instead of days compared to TTL.

Comment: With EventBridge Scheduler, is it possible to update the requests? In other words, my initial process has informed me that the timestamp related to ID 1 is scheduled for 10 minutes from now. However, before those 10 minutes have passed, I receive an update for the same ID that sets the timestamp much further into the future. Therefore, I want to trigger the lambda function for that ID with the second update, not the first one set for 10 minutes. Is this possible?

Comment: Yea you can simply call Update schedule and update it's value. You can do this from the same lambda that creates the item.

Comment: I have tested, and it is precisely the behaviour I was expecting. Thank you very much

Comment: Yea it's a really cool solution which has endless capabilities.